# CSS selector issues

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am very bad with selectors, I am trying to figure out how to make a transition happen on my form when I hover over the "create one" link. Can anyone help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/LyZxG/

```
body:hover .form{}
```

the fiddle above shows all of my code, I currently have it transitioning from "body:hover" so you can see the transition.

Thanks in advance!

ps. I have ready every form about selectors and cant figure it out, I know its simple I'm just not getting it, thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK with just css all you need to do is remove the

```
body:hover .form{}
```

add and in

```
.create-link:hover .form{
opacity:1.0;
    width:260px;
}
```

After you do that you will need to update your create link html to this

```
<li class="create-link">
    <a href="#">
    <h1 class="account-links">Create One</h1></a>
    <form class="form" action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
        Password: <input type="text" name="pass">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</li>
```

Comment: You do know the problem with opacity is that it just doesn't show but it is there so basically it will trigger the hover when you move your mouse where the link is supposed to be. Better use display:none for hiding and display:block to show.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/HM82L/

jquery code

```
$(".create-link").hover(function(){
    $(".form").addClass("form-hover");
}, function(){
    $(".form").removeClass("form-hover");
});
```

and a little bit of CSS

```
.form{height:100px; transition:all .5s;}

.form-hover{
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution.  You won't be able to do this with your current html structure.  A javascript/jquery implementation is your best bet for something like this.

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned any usage of jQuery on their page, so this solution might not be applicable at all. If a JavaScript solution is required, then it would be best to stick with vanilla JS unless OP otherwise states they are or can use jQuery. There'd also be little reason to use jQuery over vanilla JS if jQuery would be used just for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code but this should work for right now.

```
<div class="content">
    <header></header>
    <nav>
        <ul>    <a href="#"><li class="nav-box-home"><h1>Home</h1></li></a>

            <li class="nav-box-account"><a href="#"><h1>Account</h1></a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><h1 class="account-links">My Account</h1></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="create-link"><a href="#"><h1 class="account-links">Create                          One</h1></a>
 <form class="form" action="demo_form.asp" method="get">First name:
                            <input type="text" name="fname">
                            <br>Last name:
                            <input type="text" name="lname">
                            <br>Password:
                            <input type="text" name="pass">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="nav-box-time"><a href="#"><h1>Time-Saver</h1></a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <article>
                <h1>blah</h1>

                <h1>blah</h1>

                <h1>blah</h1>

                <h1>blah</h1>

        </article>
    </section>
    <section></section>
    <footer></footer>
</div>

li.create-link:hover .form {
    width:260px;
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LyZxG/2/)

**NOTE:** My advice would be to get into css basics to properly set your menu first and then get into transitions. Just move 1 step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

body .form to style the form, :hover (for the sake of cross browser support) should be on  tags. otherwise attach an onHover event to the element and throw javascript at it.